# Is it true to say that there is a single electric field and it is inhabited by and affected by all charges in the universe?

Tags: electric-fields, spacetime, universe

I don't see why or how this could be argued against or if it really matters, but that's why I ask the forum.

I am just trying to understand the nature of the fields in the universe. Am I correct in thinking that the entire universe is just a few fundamental fields laid over each other, getting influenced by the different particles that happen to interact with them?

Comment: The particles are just the quanta of the fields.

Comment: *laid over each other* There is no layering. Each of the fundamental (for now) quantum fields is simply defined over all of spacetime.

Answer (score 2):

It's a model. "[All models are wrong, some are useful](https://jamesclear.com/all-models-are-wrong)." So, the question is what the use of this idea is. There is some insight here: to achieve the isolated electric fields of textbooks often takes careful attention to shielding, and is never perfect.